# ActiveMQ change ports

Tags: port, activemq-classic, broker

When I try to start my ActiveMQ broker, I get an address already in use error:

```
2015-01-17 18:41:32,828 | ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, ID:Laptop-44709-1421516492312-0:1], java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Die Adresse wird bereits verwendet)
```

I have tried to inspect the service running in port 5672 with netstat | grep, but it doesn't show the pid for some reason. So I tried changing the default port for amqp:

```
<!--
        The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
        clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
    -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

However, when I try sudo /etc/init.d/activemq start, ActiveMQ ignores my config and keeps connecting to the port already in use.

Any ideas why?

I have been setting up ActiveMQ following this guide:
http://servicebus.blogspot.de/2011/02/installing-apache-active-mq-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: use netstat -a -o -n to have a look at pid

Comment: Start by figuring out what process is using the port. Likely, you will find out that it's another AMQ instance. So try to clear out what instance is running, who is writing the log and who is picking up your config.

Comment: Most likely, ActiveMQ is using a different config file than the one you are editing. It can be a hassle to find out which config ActiveMQ is using, especially since it can depend on the way you start it. To make sure that ActiveMQ is using the configuration file you edit, deliberately introduce a syntax error in the XML file. ActiveMQ will then complain about that and not start - that way you can make sure you edit the correct file and configure ports from there.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem with the ActiveMQ configs (JMX in particular) when I used a simlink in init.d in Ubuntu. ActiveMQ started work fine after I had replaced the simlink with a script like:

```
#! /bin/sh
ACTIVEMQ_HOME="/opt/activemq"

case "$1" in
start)
$ACTIVEMQ_HOME/bin/activemq start
;;
stop)
$ACTIVEMQ_HOME/bin/activemq stop
;;
restart)
$ACTIVEMQ_HOME/bin/activemq restart
;;
status)
$ACTIVEMQ_HOME/bin/activemq status
;;
*)
echo "Valid commands: start|stop|restat|status" >&2
;;
esac
exit 0
```